# Given two YUV images of same scene with and without shadow, detect shadow region

Tags: computer-vision

**Input**: Two YUV images of same scene. One is with shadow cast on background, other without shadow.

**Output:** Detect shadow region.

**What was tried so far and didn't work:**
My appraoch was, if Luminescence varies, but chrominance matching between the two image, then it is a shadow area. This approach did not give desired results, as I later figured out chrominance also vary in shadowed area.

Is their any easy technique to detect shadows given YUV images? I do not prefer to convert it to RGB and then calculate HSV to detect shadows.

Comment: can you share sample images to get a clear picture of how the images look like in both the situations

Comment: you cannot discuss processing a particular set of images without providing the images. what is an "easy technique"?